# Medieval style fantasy book with large black creatures as enemies

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book when I was younger (maybe 8-10 years ago) that depicted a war between knights and large black non-humanoid monsters. It was a thick book probably 500+ pages and may have had a number of knights displayed on the cover. There may have been sequels but I don't recall, I found it in the teen section of my local library. I think the monsters varied in size and came out of the earth, but could be mistaken.

I believe the characters were mostly adult men, i.e. not teenagers.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Makes me think of David Farland's [Runelords series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sum_of_All_Men).  More details would help us narrow it down.

Comment: I think there is a good chance it is the Runelords series. The description of the "Reavers" sounds spot on and the "sweet triangle" is vaguely familiar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be [The Runelords series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Runelords) by David Farland (Wolverton).

The series starts with the book below (title is *The Sum of All Men*, but that is difficult to see on the first edition).

[image: Ghostly knights anoint Gaborn Val Orden as the Earth King]

The plot follows Gaborn Val Orden  as he fights an invading army.  However, both armies soon have to fight off an invasion of Reavers.  From the Wikipedia description:

> Reavers are a massive species of subterranean creatures which bear no resemblance to any surface dwelling creature. Reavers are somewhat like insects, communicating through scents and having various "castes" which perform different functions within their "hives", though they do not have a collective intelligence. They are unchallenged masters of the Underworld.
>
> Reavers are incredibly hard to kill due to their vast size, armor-like skin and crystalline bones. The best way to slay a Reaver is to attack its brain through the mouth or the "sweet triangle", an area on the back of the Reaver's head where its bone-plates do not quite meet.

The fight against the Reavers continues for the first 4 books.

The main magic system dealt with the use of magic metal that could be made into runes that will transfer qualities from one person to another by branding.

> The main magical system of the series relies on a system of attributes which are inherent to every living creature. These attributes are transferable to and from both man and animal, so brawn from a dog can be transferred to a man. Once an individual gives an attribute to another, the giver loses that particular attribute until the death of the recipient. Each person can only give one endowment in their lifetime. Endowments include brawn (physical strength), grace (physical dexterity), wit (memory and clearness of thought), metabolism (speed at which the body's processes operate), glamor, voice, stamina, sight, hearing, smell, touch, taste, talent, will, bloodlust, and pain. Talent and will are more difficult to create and are only known by the Inkarrans. Bloodlust and pain are perverse in nature and were devised by the one true master of evil to strengthen her troops and torture the humans, specifically Fallion.

Comment: This is it! Thank you

Comment: @bphi Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

Knights vs. black non-humanoid monsters from underground sounds a lot like Barbara Hambly's [*Darwath Trilogy*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50578-darwath).  Does this cover look familiar?

[image: 1997 cover of The Time of the Dark]

In the first book (*The Time of the Dark*) Gil and Rudy are plucked from our world by the wizard Ingold Inglorion to help fight the rising of the Dark that threatens Darwath.  Gil trains as a warrior and joins the Guard to fight using normal weapons, while Rudy apprentices to Ingold as a wizard to fight using magic.

Comment: I don't think this it is, thank you for your answer though.